# The value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}$ $\ln(1+x)$ $dx]$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I evaluated it as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left.x^{n + 1}\,
\ln\left(1 + x\right)\,\right\vert_{0}^{1} -
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n + 1}\,\,\left(1 + x\right)^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right],
$$
which comes as
$$
\ln\left(2\right) -
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\int_{0}^{1}x^{n + 1}
\left(1 - x + x^{2} - x^{3}\cdots\right)\mathrm{d}x = \ln\left(2\right) - 0\ ?
$$
How to evaluate
$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n + 1} \over 1 + x}\,\mathrm{d}x\ ?$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the fact that

$$
0 \leq \frac{1}{1+x} \leq 1
$$

for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Maybe the left side inequality is `<`?

Comment: @Bernard yes, but it's not important.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.  Let

$$I_n = \int_0^1 dx \, x^n \log{(1+x)}$$

Integrate by parts to show that

$$(n+1) I_n + n I_{n-1} = 2 \log{2}-\frac1{n+1} $$

As $n \to \infty$, we get twice the sought-after limit on the LHS and $2 \log{2}$ on the RHS.  Thus, the limit in question is $\log{2}$.

Comment: Wait, this does not show that the limit exists (but does allow to compute it once one knows it exists).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\,\ln\pars{1 + x}\,\dd x}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1 - x}{=}\,\,\,&\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{n}\,\ln\pars{2 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{n\ln\pars{1 - x}}\,\,
\ln\pars{2 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nx}\,\,
\ln\pars{2 - 0}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n + 1 \over n} =
\bbx{\ln\pars{2}} \approx 0.6931\\ &
\end{align}